# Writing a more efficient version of Data.Map.findWithDefault

Tags: dictionary, haskell

`Data.Map.findWithDefault` is implemented like this:

```
findWithDefault :: Ord k => a -> k -> Map k a -> a
findWithDefault def k m = case lookup k m of
    Nothing -> def
    Just x  -> x
```

This is incredibly stupid as the `Maybe` type is not used.

I'd like to write my own lookup:

```
lookup k = k `seq` go
   where
      go Data.Map.Tip = (0,0,0,0)
      go (Data.Map.Bin _ kx x l r) =
         case compare k kx of
            LT -> go l
            GT -> go r
            EQ -> x
```

However `Data.Map` does not export `Data.Map.Tip` and `Data.Map.Bin` unless `TESTING` is enabled, and I don't know how to enable `TESTING`. See:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Data-Map.html

Comment: Well, you're not supposed to work with the internal representation of `Data.Map` (which might change without warning), only with the stable public interface. But nothing stops you from cloning / copying the source of `Data.Map` and modifying it. If you actually manage to write a more efficient version, you could even file a pull request to that everybody benefits from it – though I wonder what makes you think your version would be more efficient, I frankly doubt that.

Comment: You are looking at a 12 year old version, the latest version is 0.6.7 which does implement it without the Maybe in between: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/src/Data.Map.Internal.html#findWithDefault

Comment: Also, version 0.6.7 does export the `Tip` and `Bin` constructors (in an `*.Internal` module): https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Map-Internal.html#t:Map

Comment: What do you mean "the `Maybe` type is not used?? This is basically just a thin wrapper around `Data.Map.lookup` (which, sure, could have been written as `findWithDefault def k m = maybe def (lookup k m)` instead of a `case` expression).

Answer (score 6):

When compiling `findWithDefault`, the call to `lookup` will be inlined, which will result in the `Maybe` being eliminated.  It's a little hard to demonstrate this is true with the actual code from the `containers` package, but you can see it in the following simplified, self-contained example:

```
module MyMap where

-- a really terrible `Map`
newtype Map k v = Map [(k, v)]

myLookup :: (Eq k) => k -> Map k v -> Maybe v
myLookup k (Map m) = go m
  where go [] = Nothing
        go ((k', v): rest) | k == k' = Just v
                           | otherwise = go rest

myFindWithDefault :: (Eq k) => v -> k -> Map k v -> v
myFindWithDefault def k m = case myLookup k m of
  Nothing -> def
  Just x -> x
```

If you compile this with `ghc -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dsuppress-uniques MyMap.hs`, you'll find that the following core is generated for `myFindWithDefault`:

```
myFindWithDefault
  = \ @k @v $dEq def k1 m ->
      joinrec {
        go ds
          = case ds of {
              [] -> def;
              : ds1 rest ->
                case ds1 of { (k', v1) ->
                case == $dEq k1 k' of {
                  False -> jump go rest;
                  True -> v1
                }
                }
            }; } in
      jump go (m `cast` <Co:3>)
```

Note that there's no call to `myLookup` here, and no `Just`, `Nothing`, or `Maybe` involved.  In fact, if you add a hand-optimized definition:

```
myOptimizedFindWithDefault :: (Eq k) => v -> k -> Map k v -> v
myOptimizedFindWithDefault def k (Map m) = go m
  where go [] = def
        go ((k', v): rest) | k == k' = v
                           | otherwise = go rest
```

and recompile with the same flags, you might be a little stunned to discover that the GHC compiled code for `myOptimizedFindWithDefault` is the following:

```
myOptimizedFindWithDefault = myFindWithDefault
```

Not only does GHC automatically optimize the original `myFindWithDefault`, but it's smart enough to determine that the "incredibly stupid" and hand-optimized definitions are equivalent, and it eliminates the duplicate code.

So, even if the `findWithDefault` definition in `Data.Map` is "incredibly stupid", the incredibly smart GHC compiler makes up for it, and there's no particular reason to try optimizing it.

However, getting back to your question.  When you're trying to modify a package where the author has, unwisely, decided to keep the internals internal, you're kind of stuck.  Looking at the source code for `containers-0.4.0.0`, the only way to enable `TESTING` is to recompile `Data.Map` with a `-DTESTING` flag, and if you're going to have to recompile `Data.Map` anyway, you might as well just modify the `findWithDefault` definition directly.  The method you use to actually install a modified package will depend on how you're managing your Haskell installation and Haskell projects.

Fortunately, as was pointed out in the comments, more recent versions of `containers` export the internals in appropriately named modules, so that might be the best approach.  The following works with `containers-0.6.5.1`:

```
import Data.Map.Internal (Map(..))

findWithDefault' :: Ord k => a -> k -> Map k a -> a
findWithDefault' def k = k `seq` go
  where go Tip = def
        go (Bin _ kx x l r) =
          case compare k kx of
            LT -> go l
            GT -> go r
            EQ -> x
```

though, as was *also* pointed out in the comments, the definition of `findWithDefault` in later versions of containers has already been rewritten to look more or less like this:

```
-- actual definition form containers-0.6.5.1
findWithDefault :: Ord k => a -> k -> Map k a -> a
findWithDefault = go
  where
    go def !_ Tip = def
    go def k (Bin _ kx x l r) = case compare k kx of
      LT -> go def k l
      GT -> go def k r
      EQ -> x
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised you're in favor of exporting internals...

Comment: In brief, for open source software, exposing your internals in a clearly labeled manner makes your software more useful.  (After all, much of the motivation for distributing the source code in the first place is an acknowledgement that modifying the software by mucking with the internals is a valid use case.)

Comment: I'd mark this as answered but you made fun of my frustration

Comment: That wasn't my intention.  Were you put off by the quotation marks around "incredibly stupid"?  If not, what was your concern about the answer?